# создание интерактивного изображения

Tags: javascript, html, pwa

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть PDF документ, или любой другой векторный. На нем изображен план здания.
Нужно загружать на страницу файл плана и отмечать (например прямоугольниками) некоторые местности на плане. Необходима возможность получения координат отметок для сохранения их в базе и дальнейшего отображения плана с этими отметками, а также фильтрации (отметки должны быть тоже динамическими).
Я ломаю голову как это сделать или canvas или map, как дать пользователю возможность отмечать и как получать эти самые координаты. Наверно нужно конвертировать вектор в растр и с ним работать. Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть какие веб фреймворки для такой работы с изображениями или картами

Comment: Вы сами что то делали ?

Comment: нет, только изучаю. даже не знаю с чего начать. ищу, но не нахожу подобной информации

Comment: думаю загружать изображение и создавать новый слой поверх этого изображения. слой будет svg и рисовать на нем rect. при этом каждому rect задавать id

Comment: В каком виде у тебя исходное изображение?

Comment: в любом векторном, могу конвертировать в растр

Comment: pdf, dwg и т.д.

Comment: pdf - это не картинка

Comment: вы правы! Раньше не знал, спасибо

Comment: добавь в вопрос пример картинки и того как это должно выглядеть. Что именно должно сохраняться?

Comment: добавил. в базе должен сохраняться фон (чертеж плана), координаты красных прямоугольников, и другие свойства, которые необходимы для описания выделенных областей.

Comment: какие координаты?

Comment: Задача интересная, но тянет на полноценный проект. Могу вам ещё накинуть на вентилятор, что вам необходимо ещё и фиксировать масштаб изображений - поскольку те координаты, что наотмечают вам пользователи с ноутбука не будут соответствовать координатам отмеченым пользователям с монитора... Вообщем оно не должно быть резиновим. Ну и размеры pdf должни бить одинаковими.

Comment: по размеру изображения должна динамически создаваться область (слой) по размеру загруженного изображения. размеры области тоже будут отправляться в базу, что сделает отображение унифицированным на всех устройствах

Comment: http://www.newart.ru/htm/flash/risovalka_27.php функционал как у этой рисовалки. только рисовать не поверх белого фона, а поверх картинки

Comment: Посмотри пример тут: [Рисование svg в браузере. Возможно ли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1340910/186999)